# After installing with Wubi, can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, grub2, wubi

I installed Ubuntu (12.10) through Wubi and when I go to the dual boot screen, I choose Ubuntu. But all it does is showing me a Grub menu which says:

> this is a minimalistic command (something something..)

and I have only the option to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and see some commands. Nothing works.

Please help me guys. 
I installed it with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You landed in the GRUB Shell. this happens if some files are missing or not linked properly (or the bios is too old).

Here is a great tutorial on how to boot your Ubuntu from Grub Shell: http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/booting_grub_shell , you might have to adapt some things (like the name for the drives, he uses hda , my pc has sda , you have to look what the names on your pc are)

Comment: THAnKYOU!!!!!!!! now i have a new problem ....damn it... no sound :(

Comment: What does the "Sound" page in Options say? Maybe you have to install the driver manually, try to get a linux driver for the soundcard (don't know what your soundcard is, so can't help you more, sorry)